# How to run multiple tags at once in Cucumber / Cypress JS project?

Tags: cucumber, cypress

In my Cypress JS / Cucumber project, I am trying to run multiple test scenario's with different tags.

```
Feature: First feature

    @tagOne
    Scenario: #1 Navigation
```

Another feature:

```
Feature: Secondfeature

    @tagTwo
    Scenario: #1 Visibility
```

I'm able to run the tags seperately using the below commands:

```
npx cypress run -e TAGS=\"@tagOne\"
npx cypress run -e TAGS=\"@tagTwo\"
```

However, I now need to run them together at the same time.

When I run the below command, only `tagOne` scenario's run, & the `tagTwo` scenario is Pending.

`npx cypress run -e TAGS=\"@tagOne or @tagTwo\"`

Can someone please tell me how I can run these tags at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [syntax](https://github.com/cucumber/tag-expressions#migrating-from-old-style-tags), these are the options.

| Old style command line | Cucumber Expressions style command line |
| --- | --- |
| --tags @dev | --tags @dev |
| --tags ~@dev | --tags "not @dev" |
| --tags @foo,@bar | --tags "@foo or @bar" |
| --tags @foo --tags @bar | --tags "@foo and bar" |
| --tags ~@foo --tags @bar,@zap | --tags "not @foo and (@bar or @zap)" |

If this works the same as Boolean expressions, `or` will stop at the first one that matches.

You should try `and` instead.

```js
npx cypress run -e TAGS="@tagOne and @tagTwo"
```